# I am unable to install Composer on my local machine

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer on my local machine (Macbook Pro OSX Yosemite version 10.10.4) using the following command in terminal:

```
> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I receive the following output:

```
> #!/usr/bin/env php
> All settings correct for using Composer
>Downloading...
>Download failed: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed 
>to open stream: Operation timed out
>Downloading...
>Download failed: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed 
>to open stream: Operation timed out
>Downloading...
>Download failed: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed 
>to open stream: Operation timed out The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

I don't understand why the operation is timing out. My connection is fine. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Did you tried to ping getcomposer.org? It's seems just a networking issue... You can also visit https://getcomposer.org/installer download it manually and in the Terminal execute: php installer

Answer (score 0):

I You are having problems with your internet connection. That's why the terminal is showing Operation timeout. Check your internet settings and proxy settings. If you internet connection is ok , Go for a system restart and check your firewall.

Comment: The internet connection was fine, I'm honestly still not sure why it wouldn't work. I downloaded the composer.phar file and installed it manually no problems, for some reason the terminal would not complete the operation.

Comment: Disable k9 software